# AxesLabel in RegionPlot does not work

Tags: plotting

I simply want to add labels to the axes without using the Drawing Tools menu, I tried this without success:

`RegionPlot[x^2 + y < 3, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`

This does not work either:

`RegionPlot[x^2 + y < 3, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]`

Is there any convenient way of labelling axes in a region plot? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `FrameLabel`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using FrameLabel instead of AxesLabel I get exactly what I want, at least if I disable the automatic rotation and enlarge the font size:

`RegionPlot[x^2 + y < 3, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
     RotateLabel -> False,LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 20)]`

[image: regionplot]

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness, one can also interpret this question as meaning that you want to display axes and label them, *instead* of displaying a frame and labeling that.

In that case, the answer would be

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y < 3, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> None]
```

[image: RegionPlot with axes]

Comment: That explains it - FrameLabel works for Frame, AxesLabel for Axes, and the two are completely different things. Thanks for your answer!