# How to get grid lines at all (log) tick marks in Show function and why losing AxesLabel?

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

This question was inspired by [How to get grid lines at all (log) tick marks in Version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54613/how-to-get-grid-lines-at-all-log-tick-marks-in-version-10), which I was trying to follow to solve my problem. I am trying to plot together, in a `Show` function, a `ListLogLogPlot` and a `LogLogPlot`. I encounter the following issues:

1) when in `PlotRange` I turn the x-range from {1,10} to something like {10^-4,10^3}, the nice feature described in the overmentioned question fails. That is, I don't see the lines at each log tick anymore. The same thing happens if I change the y-range. This seems to happen when I go over a range of 6 orders of magnitude. How to get them back?

2)I also notice that using `Frame->True` makes the `AxesLabel` vanish. How to get it back?

I also tried to move these options from `LogLogPlot` to `Show`, but it fails to work as I would like.

```
Z0Num = 0.1;
Show[LogLogPlot[{beta, beta^2}, {beta, 1, 10}, 
PlotRange -> {{10^-4, 10^3}, {0.0001, 10^3}}, GridLines -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {"\[Beta]", "\.08F(\[Beta])"}, 
PlotLegends -> {{"1", "2"}, 
Placed[Grid[{{StringForm["Z0=``", NumberForm[Z0Num, 4]]}}], {{0.8,
0.9}, {1, 1}}]}, PlotLabel -> "Label"], 
ListLogLogPlot[{{1, 10}, {2, 100}}, PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True,
PlotLegends -> {"3"}], ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True]
```

These are the 2 different outputs. I am looking for something like the first one, on a wider range and with the frame together with the AxesLabels.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With regard to `AxesLabel` vanishing, consider [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16744/axeslabel-in-regionplot-does-not-work). You will need to change `AxesLabel` to `FrameLabel` to make it work with a `Frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proceed accordingly:

Define unlabeled ticks: `unl = Log10@Range[2, 9, 1] // N;`
Propagate these over the range of interest: `unl  = # + unl & /@ Range[-4, 3] // Flatten;`

Set up labeling: `lab = Range[-4, 3];`

Now we can assemble our ticks:

```
tik = Join[
   {10.^#, ""} & /@ unl,
   {10.^#, 10.^#} & /@ lab];
```

You want a grid too? Same trick but without the labels:

```
grd = Log10@Range[1, 9, 1];
grd  = # + grd & /@ Range[-4, 4] // Flatten // N;
```

Put it all together, noting that we'll use FrameLabel not axis label:-

```
LogLogPlot[{beta, beta^2}, {beta, 1, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^-3, 10^3}, {0.001, 10^3}}, GridLines -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Beta]", "\.08F(\[Beta])"},
 FrameTicks -> {{tik, tik}, {tik, tik}},
 GridLines -> grd,
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 40}, {Automatic, 15}},
 PlotLegends -> {{"1", "2"}, 
   Placed[Grid[{{StringForm["Z0=``", NumberForm[.1, 4]]}}], {{0.8, 
      0.9}, {1, 1}}]}, PlotLabel -> "Label"]
```

[image]

Interestingly, you can get away with `Gridlines->Automatic` for this plot range.

If you absolutely need your original plot range and so many grid lines, then I'd manually define those lines and use them with Prolog.